# EF 4.3 Database Migrations - Is there a way to ignore errors?

Tags: database-migration, entity-framework-4.3, entity-framework-migrations

Is there a way to ignore errors when running a manual migration?

We have client databases in different states and I need to get them all updated to the latest version.

The reason I ask about ignoring errors is because I just want to code my migration like this

```
    public override void Up()
    {   
        AddColumn("ClientUser", "LastSyncTime", c => c.Guid());
        AddColumn("ClientUser", "FileTransferToken", c => c.Guid());
        AddColumn("ClientUser", "DateFileTransferTokenIssued", c => c.DateTime());
    }
```

but naturally and expectedly it will throw an exception where the column already exists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. It is not supposed use case for EF Migrations. Migration drives database from one defined state to another defined state. If you have database in different states you need multiple migrations each covering just part of the transition.

If you want to start to use migrations in existing project with multiple databases you should first move all your databases to the same state without migrations and start to use it as initial state after which all changes will be handled only through migrations. Otherwise you will have a lot of problems.

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't answer your specific question, but it may be an answer for your problem.

Use the Database Project in VS 2010 to create a schema of your target database.

You can use this "Gold Standard" schema to compare your other databases that are in different states and produce a delta script to take it from its current schema to the target schema.

Once you are at a known state across your databases, then switch to the Database Migrations for the schema moving forward.

Keith